# How do you access other files stored on an website with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, download, navigation, html

I am trying to write a webpage for a list of files to download. The files are stored with the webpage and I want the webpage to dynamically list all the files in the folder to download. That way when more are added I don't have to modify the webpage. I know how to use JavaScript to create links on the webpage but I need to use it to find the names of the files first.

I found a website that had code for navigating files like a file browser but it only uses a string to store the current location.

This is in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

var myloc = window.location.href;
var locarray = myloc.split("/");
delete locarray[(locarray.length-1)];
var fileref = locarray.join("/");

//--></script>
```

this is in the body:

```
<form>
<input type=button value="Show Files" onClick="window.location=fileref;">
</form>
```

However this doesn't really help since I am trying to create download links to files not have a file browser.

Edit:

When you host a traditional HTML page you upload the htmlfile and any images or content for the page to what ever server you use. 
I want to use javascript to dynamically link to every file hosted with the webpage. 
I am trying to combine this with hosting the files in a Dropbox public folder for a simple way to make the files available.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you want to make a list of all the files in a folder in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of files on the server you will need to use a server-side script to gather their names:

JS--

```
//use AJAX to get the list of files from a server-side script
$.getJSON('path/to/server-side.php', { 'get_list' : 'true' }, function (serverResponse) {

    //check the response to make sure it's a success
    if (serverResponse.status == 'success') {
        var len = serverResponse.output.length,
            out = [];

        //iterate through the serverResponse variable
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            //add output to the `out` variable
            out.push('<li>' + serverResponse.output[i] + '</li>');
        }

        //place new serverResponse output into DOM
        $('#my-link-container').html('<ul>' + out.join('') + '</ul>');
    } else {
        alert('An Error Occured');
    }
});
```

PHP--

```
<?php

//check to make sure the `get_list` GET variable exists
if (isset($_GET['get_list'])) {

    //open the directory you want to use for your downloads
    $handle = opendir('path/to/directory');
    $output = array();

    //iterate through the files in this directory
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {

        //only add the file to the output if it is not in a black-list
        if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..', 'error_log'))) {
            $output[] = $file;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($output)) {

        //if there are files found then output them as JSON
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'output' => $output));
    } else {

        //if no files are found then output an error msg in JSON
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'output' => array()));
    }
} else {

    //if no `get_list` GET variable is found then output an error in JSON
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'output' => array()));
}
?>
```